# yarn create @scope/package references old version

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I've been working on a npm/yarn create script which was once published under

`@scopename/originalpackagename`

After renaming the package name

`@scopename/newpackagename`

and removing the old package from npm registry I began getting an error when running

`yarn create @scope/newpackagename somename`

```
[1/4] Resolving packages...
verbose 0.174511263 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@scope%2fnewpackagename".
verbose 0.385638523 Request "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@scope%2fnewpackagename" finished with status code 200.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
verbose 0.396535904 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@scope/originalpackagename/-/originalpackagename-1.4.0.tgz".
verbose 0.426215495 Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@scope/originalpackagename/-/originalpackagename-1.4.0.tgz: Request failed "404 Not Found"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was only tied to my local machine.

The problem was with the npm manifest located in my home directory.

`~/.config/yarn/global/package.json`
`~/.config/yarn/global/yarn.lock`

Which referenced the `@scope/oldpackagename`.

by removing the following files I was able to fix my problem.

rm ~/.config/yarn/global/package.json
rm ~/.config/yarn/global/yarn.lock